# How to skip current whole loop when error occurs?

Tags: matlab

```
for i=1:10
for i=j:5
try 
something
catch
?
end 
end
end
```

I want to try something and if it doesn't work simply stop current for loop with j and continue with next i? How to do that?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/continue.html
Continue does what you need.

Comment: somehow it doesn't work for me

Comment: To break out of the loop, use `break`. It'll skip the remaining values of `j` and go to the next iteration of `i`. Breaking out of multiple loops is more involved. BTW, I'm assuming the inner loop is `for j=1:5`, not `for i=`, because then the two loops use the same variable.